# Excel 2010 Shapes Custom Right click Context Menu

Tags: excel, vba

Okay, I've been searching for hours now. I'm simply trying to find what the control index name is for the right-click context menu for excel shapes (such as rectangles and free forms).

I have the following code, and all I want to do is delete all of the default menu items when a user right clicks a shape.

Here:

```
For Each ShapeCommandBar In Application.CommandBars("Name of Shapes Context Menu").Controls
    ShapeCommandBar.Delete
Next ShapeCommandBar
```

Comment: Just a curiosity, but why would you go through the effort of "removing formalities"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an FYI, the context menu for Shapes is apparently not accesible via VBA, so I had to wrtie my own XML for the custom file.

Article that explains is Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg469862.aspx

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's called "Shapes".

Comment: Although I think this is correct, it's apparently not accesible via VBA. Thank you for your response though!